# Express $w(z)$ in the form $w(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> $$w(z)=z^{1/2}$$

I need to express $w(z)$ in the form $w(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.

**My attempt:**

$$w(z)=\sqrt{x+iy}$$

I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z=re^{i\theta}$$
$$e^{i\theta}= cos\theta+isin\theta$$
$$\rightarrow z^{1/2}=(re^{i\theta})^{1/2}$$
$$\rightarrow r^{1/2}e^{\frac{1}{2}i\theta}= r^{1/2}( cos\frac{1}{2}\theta+isin\frac{1}{2}\theta)$$
$$tan \theta = \frac{y}{x}$$
$$r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\rightarrow  {(x^2+y^2)}^{\frac{1}{4}} cos(\frac{1}{2}tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))+i{(x^2+y^2)}^{\frac{1}{4}}sin(\frac{1}{2}tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))$$
$$u(x,y)={(x^2+y^2)}^{\frac{1}{4}} cos(\frac{1}{2}tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))$$
$$v(x,y)={(x^2+y^2)}^{\frac{1}{4}}sin(\frac{1}{2}tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x}))$$

Comment: This assumes that $\theta = \arctan \left(\frac y x\right)$, however that is only true if $x>0$, which may or may not be a fair assumption. See the [atan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) for a general computation.